# Compare one filed in different csv using Pentaho

Tags: javascript, pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I have 2 csv files .

1) CSV that contains 10 records and one filed named city . This field has value in short forms like "M" for "Melbourne",  etc .
2) Second CSV has two fields like , "cityshortname" and "city" .

What i want to do is compare the first csv with the second csv and replace the "M" with "Melbourne" using second CSV as a reference .

How can i achieve this using Pentaho ?
Any Help would be appreciable .

Answer (score 0):

Proceed like in [How to validate one csv data compare with another csv file using Pentaho?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50017225/how-to-validate-one-csv-data-compare-with-another-csv-file-using-pentaho/50018038#50018038).

Tell the `Stream lookup` step to use "M" as `key(s) to lookup the value(s)` [upper table] and "Melbourne" as the `field(s) to retrieve` [lower table]. Of course it is not really "M" and "Melbourne" but the name of the fields which you get from the drop-down.